expo build using "eas build" failing
i get this error in the prebuild section
✖ Prebuild failed
Error: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/expo/workingdir/build/path/to/file.ttf'
here is my project structure
project files hierarchy
i tried running
"npx expo install --fix"
"npx expo doctor"
"npm audit fix"
and none of them solved the problem!

it turns out i had a faulty path in my app.json
